# Loop over character vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, character

I am trying to build a loop for() to draw & save a ggplot for a list of genes in a dataset.
My initial code is the following:

```
for(i in genelist){
  plot <- ggplot() +
           geom_density(data = mydata, aes(x=log2(i)), fill="pink", alpha = 0.5) +
           xlab(paste("log2 ", i))
  ggsave(plot, filename = paste("plot_",i ,".png"))
  }
```

genelist is a chr vector.

mydata is a dataframe where colnames are names of genes, rownames are patients barcodes and matrix is count values.

I obtained the following error:

*Saving 11.3 x 5.98 in image
Error in log2(i) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function*

Since the error seems to come from the plot saving, I tried the code without:

```
for(i in genelist){
  plot <- ggplot() +
           geom_density(data = mydata, aes(x=log2(i)), fill="pink", alpha = 0.5) +
           xlab(paste("log2 ", i))
   }
```

The loop went to the end without error (i = my last gene in genelist) but when I tried to display the plot:

*Error in log2(i) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function*

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. But the problem most likely is you trying to use `i` in the `aes()` which is lady evaualted. Maybe `aes(x=log2(.data[[i]]))` would work. Also use `paste0()` rather than `paste()` to make sure your file names don't have spaces.

Comment: That works great, thanks! Could you please explain me .data[[i]] syntax? In my limited knowledge of R, [[ ]] is used to subset a list. Does it mean that .data[[i]] tells to take data from the list "i" and since "i" is a gene name corresponding to a column of mydata (dataframe columns are lists, right?) it returns its values? Why is does not work with [[i]] only?

Comment: `.data` is a "magic" variable that ggplot creates for you when plotting. It makes it easier to subset the data via character value just as you are trying to do. It's a way to avoid using the `!!sym()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write a function :

```
library(ggplot2)

plot_save <- function(i) {
    plot <- ggplot() +
             geom_density(data = mydata, aes(x=log2(!!sym(i)), 
                          fill="pink", alpha = 0.5)) +
             xlab(paste("log2 ", i))

    ggsave(plot, filename = paste0("plot_",i ,".png"))
}
```

and pass `genelist` to the function.

```
lapply(genelist, plot_save)
```

Comment: That worked perfectly too thanks! Same here, could you explain me the !!sym(i) syntax?

Comment: `genelist` is a character vector, using `sym` we convert the character value to symbol.